# What application uses local address "127.0.0.1" and foreign address "screenshots"

Tags: netstat

I have discovered in the output of `netstat -a` over 250 entries like this:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:49671        screenshots:49670      ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:49670        screenshots:49671      ESTABLISHED
```

where most of them are in pairs like that, but some are not. Most have state = `ESTABLISHED` (like those), but some have `TIME_WAIT`.

These appear right after a fresh boot, but seem to "grow" over time (starting at 256 entries and growing to 273, for example).

The port range is pretty much contiguous from 49668 to 50007, but also has 5354, 5905, 6109, 16992, 27015, 31067, and some sporadic ones above 50007.

This is a relatively new Windows 10 Pro PC. I'm not sure when this behavior started, as it only recently became a problem because I use one of the ports its grabbing (50040) for a port forward of my own definition.

Anyone know what application is setting up all these "connections"?

=================== Update ==================

I had rebooted when I first discovered that port 50040 was in use by something other than my own port forward definition, and it hasn't yet come back in use. I'll keep watching for it. Thanks to @Appleoddity and @barlop I now know how to find the process that's using it.

And FWIW, the majority of the "pairs" of ports in use are by `IntelTechnologyAccessService`, which is apparently part of `Intel Online Connect`.

Comment: You mean connections to your own machine? 127.0.0.1 is localhost which is the machine itself

Comment: Right. I want to know what is establishing connections from localhost to "screenshots", whatever that is...

Comment: You have not supplied enough information to determine that.  Can’t even determine what host is being connected to since you retracted that information for some reason.  It could be Amazon cloud address for all we know.  Edit your question provide specifics

Comment: Umm, I gave EXACTLY what's in the netstat -a output. The local address is "127.0.0.1" (which we agree is localhost), and the foreign is "screenshots". That's it. No .com or anything else. I admit that I didn't list all 250+ of them, but I can't see how seeing all of the identical entries (except for ports) will help determine the application creating the connections...

Comment: So what up address does *screenshots* resolve to?

Comment: Try `netstat -an` to see only addresses and not names.

Comment: I strongly suggest -aon  for PID you can then check in task manager

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc - Thanks for making my post look better. I'm new to this and don't yet know all the markup syntax.

Comment: @Ramhound - "screenshots" doesn't resolve to anything (host not found).

Comment: @DanielSpencer So you do have an entry in your hosts file.  Firefox is the culprit.

Comment: @Ramhound No, Firefox is not the culprit. Apparently you didn't read my comment on Appleoddity's answer with a link to support.mozilla where they say Firefox doesn't touch etc/hosts. It turns out that my company's IT department says "The Firefox screenshots service was deemed as a security risk since it could enable users to accidentally leak data to Mozilla which is subsequently accessible from the Internet, so the decision was made to block access". They apparently install a utility on all company PCs that continually checks to see that etc/hosts has the redirection in it.

Comment: Your right I didn’t read the comments because they are extremely noisy and the information wasn’t contained in the question.  You didn’t mention corporate network in your question

Answer (score 3):

You’re using the wrong command.

Use `netstat -abn | more` from an administrative command prompt and it will tell you what application attached to each port, one page at a time.

The -n will show IP addresses instead of hostnames like `screenshots.` Which, by the way, is probably your computer’s name.

The -b will show the application that owns the port.

Comment: `-aon` is good   the -o  doesnt require administrative and shows PID so with -o you dont really need -b.   -b is good though one should know(besides that it requires administrative as you point out),  it shows process name on the next line, which makes it not immediately clear, and makes output double the lines.

Comment: Appleoddity and @barlop - Thanks very much for the tips on netstat command. Both -abn and -aon are useful.

Comment: "screenshots" isn't my computer name, but that thought did make me look in `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, which lo and behold had this

    `127.0.0.1 screenshots.firefox.com`

which FireFox apparently puts back every time it starts. That's a topic for a different question.

Comment: @DanielSpencer You can set the screenshot facility to disabled: [Firefox Screenshots](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-screenshots).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I already had `extensions.screenshots.disabled` set to `true`. I'm not sure now what the trigger is that put the entry back in `etc/hosts`. I restarted FireFox just now and it didn't add it. Maybe it does it after a reboot. I'll check that next time I reboot.

Comment: Oh, and Mozilla claims they don't do it. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1208052 . Weird, if it's not FireFox itself I wonder what I have on this laptop that feels the need to make that entry. Doesn't seem to be hurting anything, now that I know it's there...